# How to resolve "Not all features are shown" in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I need use a feature layer which includes 7000 features in SceneView. But the HTML page only shows part of data, and the error shows:

[esri.layers.graphics.controllers.SnapshotController] Feature limit exceeded on layer "Community". Not all features are shown.

The MaxRecordCount is set as 10000.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_feature_layers.html :

> its limit [..] is 500 for ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 and 1000 for ArcGIS Server 10, but this limit is configurable using the Parameters tab of the Service Properties dialog box in ArcCatalog or Manager.

So i suggest you update that feature layer's property and publish it again